# Python: Accessing List Elements From Other Class Methods

Tags: python, list, class-method

I'm trying to access the 6th element in my list (from a different class method) using a `for` loop.

This is what the list would consist of:

`personalInfo = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password', 'birthdate', 'alias']`

And this is the code that I am running to try and get the alias, thus leading to me needing to get the password:

edit: Just decided to include the whole class in case I miss anything small.

```
class Account:

accountInfo = {}

def __init__(self):
    choice = raw_input("Would you like to login or signup?\n")
    if choice.lower() == "login":
        self.login()

    elif choice.lower() == "signup":
        print "Great! Fill in the following."
        self.signup()

    else:
        self.__init__()

def signup(self):

        accountID = '%010x' % random.randrange(16**10)
        personalInfo = []

        firstName = raw_input("First Name: ")
        lastName = raw_input("Last Name: ")
        email = raw_input("E-Mail: ")
        password = raw_input("Password: ")
        birthdate = raw_input("DOB (DD/MM/YYYY): ")
        alias = raw_input("Username/Alias: ")

        personalInfo.append(firstName)
        personalInfo.append(lastName)
        personalInfo.append(email)
        personalInfo.append(password)
        personalInfo.append(birthdate)
        personalInfo.append(alias)

        self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo
        self.personalInfo = personalInfo

        print self.accountInfo

def login(self):

    self.alias = raw_input("Username/Alias: ")

    for i in self.personalInfo:
        if self.alias == self.personalInfo[5]:

            self.password = raw_input("Password: ")

            if self.password == True:
                print "You have successfully logged on."
            else:
                self.password

        else:
            self.password

        print self.alias, self.password
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

`File "liveShare.py", line 122, in login
    for i in self.personalInfo:
AttributeError: Account instance has no attribute 'personalInfo'`

Also, I apologize if some of my code doesn't make sense logically. I'm new to this, so there are probably some obvious mistakes but please rip me to shreds criticism wise. I want to learn the correct way.

All help is appreciated :)

Comment: if `personalInfo` is defined within the `Account` class, then you could just define it as `self.personalInfo = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password', 'birthdate', 'alias']`.

Comment: There seems to be some context missing. What is the for loop even for? You never use `i`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I tried that but it didn't seem to work. I could have forgotten within editing thought, so I'll give it a try again.

Comment: @gilch Yeah, I tried to keep it concise as well as I thought it would be enough to answer. I can edit the rest in if I was wrong. And as far as the `i` in my `for` loop, it's the only way I've been taught to represent "each item" in the list.

Comment: What we really want is an  [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Try to reduce your code to illustrate the problem only, but completely.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Oh! I couldn't do that because these are the names of the variables that are appended onto the list. I was getting multiple errors when changing every `personalInfo` to `self.personalInfo` so I just did `self.personalInfo = personalInfo` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks you can use this method to get access to the attributes of another Class

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.personalInfo = args
def print_Info(self):
    print self.personalInfo
foo = Foo(['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password', 'birthdate', 'alias'])
print_Info(foo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't show the Account class's **init** method (should be right after the class declaration), but make sure you clearly define the variable name in the arguments.  This will ensure it is named correctly and passed to following methods.

```
def __init__(personalInfo=[]):
    self.personalInfo = personalInfo
..
#then later (or in another script that imports Account):
acct = Account(['John', 'Doe', 'email', 'password', '1/1/99', 'JohnDoe Alias'])
```